# PHP form processing with variableform inputs

Tags: php, html, forms, webforms

Got a form that has the option to add many inputs for ordering pictures via picture number.

In theory a customer could order 1 picture or 100, how would I go about the PHP.

As coding up to 100 `$_POST[]` for each possible field seems crazy as each of the added fields as it's own unique NAME attr using jQuery.

Anyone got any bright ideas?

Comment: What do you have so far? And I'm not 100% clear on what you're requesting.

Comment: Well I've got the possibility of having upto 100 form fields all with unique NAME attr. So I need to POST the information from the form.

Answer (score 4):

Using field names that end in square brackets will cause PHP to create the entries as an array:

```
<input name="foo[]" value="foo" />
<input name="foo[]" value="bar" />
<input name="foo[]" value="moo" />
<input name="foo[]" value="cow" />
```

will produce the following: `$_REQUEST['foo']` (or `$_POST['foo']`/`$_GET['foo']`) is an array like this:

```
array(
    0 => 'foo',
    1 => 'bar',
    2 => 'moo',
    3 => 'cow'
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like

```
for ($i=0;$i<100;$i++){
    if (isset($_POST['picture'.$i])){
        // Do something
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```
<input type="checkbox" value="picnumber" name="pictures[]" />

<?php
$pics = $_POST['pictures']; // here you will get an array of values of the selected images
?>
```

Comment: Unfortunataly I've got a text input for the picture name, and a select box for each picture with picture sizes.